# How to make text using javascript and youtube api clickable

Tags: javascript, html, json, youtube-api

Right now I have a base html page that gets the most popular videos using youtubes api. So far it displays the title of the videos but i'm trying to make those titles clickable. If the title was clicked they would then just be brought to the video on actual youtube. I know that I could theoretically just find the most popular videos then do a clickable link but I want this to more or less auto update everytime a new popular video gets found with the youtube api. Right now I have this basic code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Videos</title>
<style>
.titlec {
    font-size: small;
}
ul.videos li {
    float: left;
    width: 10em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
ul.videos {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    padding-left : 0em;
    margin-left: 0em;
    list-style: none;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://swfobject.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/swfobject/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function showData(data) {
  var feed = data.feed;
  var entries = feed.entry || [];
  var html = ['<ul class="videos">'];
  for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
    var entry = entries[i];
    var title = entry.title.$t.substr(0, 20);
  //  var thumbnailUrl = entries[i].media$group.media$thumbnail[0].url;
    html.push('<span class="titlec">', title, '...</span><br /></span></li>');
  }
// html.push('</ul><br style="clear: left;"/>');
  document.getElementById('videos2').innerHTML = html.join('');
  if (entries.length > 0) {
    loadVideo(entries[0].media$group.media$content[0].url, false);
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="playerContainer" style="width: 20em; height: 180px; float: left;">
  <object id="player">
  </object>
</div>
<div id="videos2"></div>
<script 
    type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_popular?time=this_week&alt=json-in-script&callback=showData&max-results=10&format=5">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I exactly understand what you are trying to achieve but I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FDxHH/20/)!

Here is the code:

```
<html>    
<head>
    <title>My Videos</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://swfobject.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/swfobject/swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showData(data) {
            var feed = data.feed;
            var entries = feed.entry || [];
            var html = ['<ul class="videos">'];
            for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
                var entry = entries[i];
                var title = entry.title.$t.substr(0, 20);
        html.push('<li class="titlec"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="loadVideo('+"'"+ entry.media$group.media$content[0].url +"'"+');">' + title + '</a></li>');
            }

            document.getElementById('videos2').innerHTML = html.join('') + '</ul>';
            if (entries.length > 0) {
                loadVideo(entries[0].media$group.media$content[0].url);
            }
        }

        function loadVideo(e) {
            var container = document.getElementById('playerContainer');
            var player = document.getElementById('player');
            container.removeChild(player);//remove object child
            player.setAttribute('data',e);//change link
            container.appendChild(player);//add object back
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="playerContainer" style="width: 20em; height: 180px; float: left;">
        <object id="player"></object>
    </div>
    <div id="videos2"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_popular?time=this_week&alt=json-in-script&callback=showData&max-results=10&format=5">

    </script>
</body>
```